# Impala - How to compare a timestamp with date

Tags: sql, impala

In Impala, when I tried to compare a field containing timestamp to a certain date

```
select * from raw.mm_alert_task_history where to_date(alert_date_dt)>= to_date(cast('26/11/2020' as timestamp))
```

It returns 0 row eventhough when i checked the data manually, there is rows containing timestamp more than that date. I have been having difficulty in dealing with dates in impala. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `date '2020-11-21'`?

Answer (score -1):

In  your SQL, `to_date()` will return string so your comparison wont work.
Assuming `alert_date_dt` is a timestamp/date data type, you need to compare them like this -
`where alert_date_dt>= to_timestamp('26/11/2020', 'dd/MM/yyyy')`
Sometimes, you may need to remove timestamp sometime while comparing. Pls use below code in such case.
`where trunc(alert_date_dt,'dd')>= to_timestamp('26/11/2020', 'dd/MM/yyyy')`

Here `to_timestamp` will convert any string to timestamp with provided format. As far as i know date to timestamp conversion should be automatic, if not and you are facing issues, pls let me know.